# Is Salesforce 2FA supported using only SMS or Email and not the Authenticator Application?

Tags: authentication, login, two-factor-authentication

I am trying to do two-factor authentication via email or SMS. 2FA via the authenticator app isn't an option as we cannot install anything on user phones.

Native [Identify Verification](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=activating_computer.htm&type=5) codes would work perfectly if there was a way to hide the "remember this device" button or some way to force a user to re-verify every time.

Has anyone been able to finagle SF to send verification codes every time a user tries to log in?

Comment: If it is 2FA and you want to send the verification code to SMS or Email then where this code to be authenticated again? btw, many companies don't want to prefer Email route.

Comment: @SantanuBoral, Not really sure what you mean. After a user enters their username and password I want them to be prompted for an additional code to enter. Users should receive that code via either email or SMS.

Comment: After receiving the code where they will enter the code and validated?